# request.FILES is empty though form tag contains multipart data encryption

Tags: python, html, django, forms, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to database from frontend HTML form. Here is the code:

**createuser.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createuser(request):

    authority = Authority.objects.only('authority')
    designation = Authority.objects.only('designation')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST:
            post = CustomUser()
            post.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            post.middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
            post.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
            post.emp_code = request.POST.get('emp_code')
            post.email = request.POST.get('email')
            passwrd = request.POST.get('password')
            post.password = make_password(passwrd)
            post.joining_date = request.POST.get('joining_date')
            # post.authority = request.POST.get('authority')
            # post.designation = Designation.objects.get(designation=request.POST.get('designation'))
                        
            post.language = request.POST.getlist('lang')
            post.address = request.POST.get('address')
            post.education = request.POST.get('education')
            post.blood_group = request.POST.get('blood_group')
            post.emergency_contact = request.POST.get('emergency_contact')
            post.relation = request.POST.get('relation')
            post.created_by = request.user
            
            myfile = request.FILES['myfile']  
            # generates multivalue dict error as multivalueDict is empty
            print(myfile)
           
            # fs = FileSystemStorage()
            # filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            # uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)               
            # print(uploaded_file_url)
            post.save()
            s = '/usermanage/userdashboard'
            return redirect(s)

    userforminfo = CreateUser.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'usermanage/createuser.html', context={"userforminfo": userforminfo, "authority":authority, "designation":designation})
```

**Output**

<MultiValueDict: {}>

The output must be a file which I am selecting. Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: What if you remove the `if request.POST` check?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It won't work for the rest of the field then. Anyways I tried removing it but did not work.

Comment: @DhatriKapuiya: can post the full logging of the request?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated view.py in code above.

Comment: I am facing same issue, any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue, here my issue is I directly passed the file data without `FormData` in the Rest API.

```
var formData = new FormData();
Array.from(files).forEach(f => formData.append('file', f))
```

using the above code, I passed the `FormData` to the POST API, my issue got resolved.

Comment: This is also a possible solution. The issue was solved after I started from scratch and wrote the same code again!!